# Same size of Kinect Circle Button inside a Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, kinect

I am developing a WPF interface using the Kinect SDK KinectCircleButton.
In particular, I have to dynamically fill a grid with a variable number of KinectCircleButton. 
The problem is that since the labels of the buttons are of variable length, it makes the buttons to be rendered of different sizes, adapting their dimension to fill the available space. I can't use absolute positioning or size, so the attributes "width" and "height" are set to "auto". 
I just would like to make the text adaptable to the available space (both scaling it or breaking it into two lines) but at the same time have every circle of the same size.

For the sake of clarity I am attaching a screenshot of my current GUI: 
[image: myGUI]

defined with the following XAML code:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Name="ButtonsGrid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="33*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <k:KinectCircleButton Name="CategoryButton1" Margin="10" Foreground="{x:Static c:Constants.TEXT_COLOR}" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="SansSerif" FontSize="48" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <k:KinectCircleButton Name="CategoryButton2" Margin="10" Foreground="{x:Static c:Constants.TEXT_COLOR}" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="SansSerif" FontSize="48" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <k:KinectCircleButton Name="CategoryButton3" Margin="10" Foreground="{x:Static c:Constants.TEXT_COLOR}" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" FontFamily="SansSerif" FontSize="48" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <k:KinectCircleButton Name="CategoryButton4" Margin="10" Foreground="{x:Static c:Constants.TEXT_COLOR}" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="SansSerif" FontSize="48" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <k:KinectCircleButton Name="CategoryButton5" Margin="10" Foreground="{x:Static c:Constants.TEXT_COLOR}" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="SansSerif" FontSize="48" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
            <k:KinectCircleButton Name="CategoryButton6" Margin="10" Foreground="{x:Static c:Constants.TEXT_COLOR}" Width="auto" Height="auto" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" FontFamily="SansSerif" FontSize="48" FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
        </Grid>
```

As you can see, the first button is bigger than the others, so the goal is to have the same size for all buttons.

Comment: Can you edit the template of the `Button` and find the `Path` that makes the circle to set width/height values on it so it always remains the same no matter what?

Comment: The point is that I want the circle to have a variable width/height, but it shouldn't depend on the length of the text specified in the label attribute

Comment: You'll still have to get down to the template level to see how its made. Whether you want to change its layout so its not effected by the length of text or not, however its templated determines how it will render.